# Trainline appears to charge tickets for walking - what am I missing?

Tags: tickets, transportation, london, trainline

I was looking at a [ticket from London Waterloo to London Bridge](https://www.thetrainline.com/buytickets/combinedmatrix.aspx?Command=TimeTable#Journey/LONDON%20WATERLOO/LONDON%20BRIDGE/22/12/16/07/00/Leave%20After//////Leave%20After/1/0//).  Most routes show a 1 change (walk to Waterloo East, get train, total 9 minutes).

However, there's one option that has 0 changes, and takes 25 minutes.

As far as I can tell, it's just meaning WALK, as it says "Make your way" for means of transportation.

However, it still has a ticket for sale for £5.90, which implies that maybe it's on a form of transportation?

Comment: I suspect it's a bug, since NRE doesn't show this journey and Trainline says "This journey is not by train". I imagine the £5.90 is the cost of a journey from London Waterloo to London Bridge as determined by the National Fares Manual (and so if you were to actually try to buy that ticket, you'd get one issued for that route), but since the only practical route is via Waterloo East, that's the ticket that you're normally sold.

Comment: @waiwai933 I have access to Sabre and it's in there too, bizarrely - as a 'transfer'.

Comment: For sure also a bug, no one will check all the journeys. Maybe write an Email and state that you found a bug. Would be interesting to see the answer

Comment: wear and tear on the pavement has to be paid somehow...

Comment: Why will you not use the tube (£2.40) ?

Comment: @DumbCoder I would, I was just curious about this option it's presenting me.

Comment: Haha, it looks like the system has got confused. It's suggesting that you walk, it's seen that "day tickets" aren't valid for that route, it's seen that "first day" tickets aren't valid for that route, but instead of thinking "wait, do you even need a ticket?", it's presenting you with the default 'all routes' ticket type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gathering the comments into an answer:

1. NRE doesn't show this journey
2. Trainline says "This journey is not by train"
3. It is present in SABRE as "transfer".
4. While the system recognizes day tickets are not valid for this route so it presents an "all route" ticket type as present in the National Fares Manual.